# Passing state setter to child with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following code;
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-sunset-c385l?file=/src/MainMenu.tsx)

**App.tsx:**

```
interface IAppDisplayMap {
  [key: string]: (props : IAppComponentProps) => JSX.Element
}

interface IAppComponentProps {
  setAppDisplay: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>
}

const appDisplayMap : IAppDisplayMap = {
  "MainMenu": MainMenu
}

export default function App() {
  const [appDisplay, setAppDisplay] = useState("MainMenu");

  const AppComponent = useMemo(() => appDisplayMap[appDisplay], [appDisplay]);
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {AppComponent ? <AppComponent setAppDisplay={setAppDisplay} /> : "Invalid AppComponent"}
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

**MainMenu.tsx:**

```
export default function MainMenu({setAppDisplay}) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      MainMenu
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

My problem is that TS complains that setAppDisplay is typed as 'Any'.
With the following code:

```
export default function MainMenu({setAppDisplay} : IAppComponentProps) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      MainMenu
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

The error disappears, but shouldn't setAppDisplay infer it's type from the parent regardless?

Comment: It should infer it. Could you paste the error and on which line it happens here?

Comment: @dobrinov Sure. I've added a codesandbox link above.

Comment: See [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/type-inference-in-typescript-9e4170de9e70). Sometimes TypeScript isn't smart enough. For example, if you have three classes that all extend a class and a array of them, sometimes TypeScript will not notice that they all extend a subclass.

Comment: Ahh got it :) The error happens in the definition of the MainMenu component. The reason why it is happening is that the param in `MainMenu` does not have anything to do with the `setAppDisplay` function in the other component. Try changing its name and you will still get the same type error. To fix it you will have to specify its type,which is `(value: string) => void`. Here is a fixed version:https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-rubin-3y114?file=/src/MainMenu.tsx